# Valgrind memory leak reported in QT list append

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, valgrind, qlist

I am using a serializer in QT C++. It looks ok but valgrind (memcheck tool) is reporting a memory leak on this function.

Valgrind cmd: `valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full`

```
QDataStream &operator>>( QDataStream &in, QList<AppNodeRecord *> *objAppNodeListRecord)
{
    quint32 len;
    in >> len;

    objAppNodeListRecord->clear();
    for(quint32 i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        AppNodeRecord *tmp=new AppNodeRecord;
        in >> tmp;
        objAppNodeListRecord->append(tmp);

        if (in.atEnd())
            break;
    }
    return in;
}
```

Valgrind reports that this instance is not freed but it is been used in the QList.

```
AppNodeRecord *tmp=new AppNodeRecord;
```

Valgrind output:

```
==19503== 1,445 (68 direct, 1,377 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1,540 of 1,568
==19503==    at 0x4026351: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:255)
==19503==    by 0x8058562: operator>>(QDataStream&, QList<AppNodeRecord*>*) (zbDbs_NodeMgmt.cpp:206)
==19503==    by 0x804D53C: main (main.cpp:53)
```

Could it be a valgrind issue?

Comment: what does "in >> tmp;" do? Does it fill the AppNodeRecord it points to or change the value of the pointer?

Comment: It is a deserializer. It fills the object with innformation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `QList` isn't responsible for deallocating the `AppNodeRecord` pointers you append to it, you have to do it manually (`qDeleteAll` might help in that case).

But as usual, for lack of a good reason, use `QList<AppNodeRecord>` to avoid this hassle in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind memcheck only tells you that there is a memory leak. If, as in your case, there is one, it reports the function where the memory allocation happened (the `new` statement).

To get rid of this leak, you have to delete all the elements that have been dynamically allocated. In your case, as Idan K wrote, you can use the generic Qt algorithm `qDeleteAll(objAppNodeListRecord)`for instance in the destructor of your class or you can use a more explicit version as follow:

```
foreach (AppNodeRecord *element, objAppNodeListRecord)
{
  delete element;
}
```